# Create folder during install module

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

So, I create module, which implement import/export some data. Everything work fine. The logic of import in next : I take a file in `var/[module_name]/import/`. (This file will be put by some another service)

My question is: What is the best way to create this folders `[module_name]/import` when some one will take my module in other project?

I think about to write instruction ('create folder in var...'), and also I think about installer, but I guess it is not good idea

Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a separate extension for import/export just add this in the install script of you extension:

```
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->checkAndCreateFolder(Mage::getBaseDir('var').DS.'[module_name]'.DS.'import');
```

It will create the folder with `777` permissions.

Comment: Thanks, but I read something like in installer is only for some issue with db. But, ok thanks again!!)

Comment: @sergio. yes usually the install script is for changing the db, but it works for folders also.

Answer (score 2):

I think that extension which creates files in that folder should take responsibility of creating that folder.

If your extension just reads files from the folder, than you can specify the path to directory as  config value and make in editable from backend.

In this case admin could specify in which folder to search import files.